# What class is suitable for screen recording in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on an app that should capture the screen image and stream it in real time to a Smart TV Java app via UDP socket.

At the moment I tried to just get a bitmap, but this works only for a current activity - I need to record the screen even when the app works in background mode. Also I checked the MediaRecorder class, but it writes the output into the file, so it requires too many conversions to get byte array which is required by DatagramPacket.

```
// current code that records only a single activity
class ScreenRecorder {
    public static Bitmap takeScreenshot(View v) {
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        v.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return b;
    }

    public static Bitmap takeScreenshotOfRootView(View v) {
        return takeScreenshot(v.getRootView());
    }
}
```

I'd like to find a class that provides methods for background screen recording and output that can be easily converted into byte[]. The expected frame rate should be about 20-30 fps.

Comment: "I'd like to find a class that provides methods for background screen recording" -- at the app level, you have exactly one option: the media projection APIs, on Android 5.0+.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll check it out.